# How to populate auth.groups and auth.group_permissions tables with initial data in Django project

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

#### Context

I am using PostgreSQL.

I would like to immediately populate the `auth.groups` and `auth.group_permissions` tables, after the very first migration of my project.

So, after I have set up these tables the way I want them, I dump them by running

```sh
python manage.py dumpdata auth.groups auth.group_permissions > core/fixtures/initial_data.json
```

The resulting file is this

```json
[
  {
    "model": "auth.group",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "name": "Admin",
      "permissions": [
        29,
        31,
        32,
        33,
        34,
        35,
        36
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "auth.group",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
      "name": "Operators",
      "permissions": [
        42,
        43,
        44,
        39,
        40
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "auth.group_permissions",
    "pk": 12,
    "fields": {
      "group": 1,
      "permission": 32
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "auth.group_permissions",
    "pk": 13,
    "fields": {
      "group": 1,
      "permission": 33
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "auth.group_permissions",
    "pk": 14,
    "fields": {
      "group": 1,
      "permission": 34
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "auth.group_permissions",
    "pk": 15,
    "fields": {
      "group": 1,
      "permission": 35
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "auth.group_permissions",
    "pk": 16,
    "fields": {
      "group": 1,
      "permission": 36
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "auth.group_permissions",
    "pk": 17,
    "fields": {
      "group": 1,
      "permission": 29
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "auth.group_permissions",
    "pk": 18,
    "fields": {
      "group": 1,
      "permission": 31
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "auth.group_permissions",
    "pk": 19,
    "fields": {
      "group": 2,
      "permission": 39
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "auth.group_permissions",
    "pk": 20,
    "fields": {
      "group": 2,
      "permission": 40
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "auth.group_permissions",
    "pk": 21,
    "fields": {
      "group": 2,
      "permission": 42
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "auth.group_permissions",
    "pk": 22,
    "fields": {
      "group": 2,
      "permission": 43
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "auth.group_permissions",
    "pk": 23,
    "fields": {
      "group": 2,
      "permission": 44
    }
  }
]
```

#### The problem

To try this, I drop and recreate my db, so that it's completely fresh, and after the first `migrate` command, I run

```sh
python manage.py loaddata initial_data.json
```

And here I get the error

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture '/home/uname/Workspace/project/core/fixtures/initial_data.json':

> Could not load auth.Group_permissions(pk=12): duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_group_permissions_group_id_permission_id_0cd325b0_uniq"
> DETAIL:  Key (group_id, permission_id)=(1, 32) already exists.

which is pretty confusing for me. How can it throw about a duplicate key when these 2 tables are completely empty at this point? How do I get it to populate these two tables with these initial data?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like the data is duplicated, the "Admin" group already has the permission id `32` in it's `permissions` list. Try removing all the `auth.group_permissions` entries from your dump

Comment: But they are in fact empty though, take a look: the `group_permissions` table: https://i.imgur.com/dWJOqFH.png and the `group` table: https://i.imgur.com/xEQvKh5.png Does it populate the `group_permissions` table the same time it populates the `group` table, based on the info for that?

Comment: Well, damn, it does. If you feel like writing these as an answer I'd be glad to accept it

Comment: Glad it helped, added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fixture is loaded in a single transaction and there is duplicate data in your dump.

The first `auth.group` entry with name "Admin" defines all of it's permissions in a list, this includes the permission with id `32`. The first `auth.group_permissions` entry then duplicates this data which cause the exception as the same data was loaded earlier in the transaction

Removing all of the `auth.group_permissions` entries from the dump JSON or excluding `auth.group_permissions` from the `dumpdata` command is the solution